# More compact Algorithm template in Latex

Tags: templates, algorithms

All,

I am using the following Algorithm template:

```
    \usepackage{algorithmicx}
    \usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}

\vspace{-0.2cm}%
\alglanguage{pseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\small
\caption{Delete item from Hash Table (with mCBF and aCBF)}
\label{Algorithm:delete_mCBF_aCBF}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{$\mathbf{DeleteItem}$}{item $x$}
    \LineComment{\emph{Quick check if $x$ is in mCBF}}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
            \If {$mCBF.C_{f_i(x)\%N}$ == 0}
                \State \textbf{return}
            \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \LineComment{\emph{Look up $x$ in $aCBF_1\cdot\cdot\cdot aCBF_k$}}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
        \If {\textbf{CBF\_query}($aCBF_i$, $x$) == \textbf{TRUE}}
            \State $j \gets C_{f_i(x)\%N}$
            \For {item $y \in B_j$}
                \If {$y.key == x$}
                    \Comment \emph{found}
                    \State \emph{remove $y$ from hash table}
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\Statex
\end{algorithmic}
  \vspace{-0.4cm}%
\end{algorithm}
```

And I get this:

[image]

However, there are too many lines of `end if` and `end for`. Is there any more compact Algorithm template that does not contain these lines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package `algpseudocode` provides some options. One option is `noend`. So you can load:

```
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

And the result is:

> [image]

Comment: Wow, this [noend] option is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: How can I remove the line numbers?

Comment: @lhhNJU: There is no special option. You can try: `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}`

Comment: If I want to split the pseudocode into two chunks and place them on side-by-side minipages (to save space when there are page limit constraints), how do make the line number start with the correct number on the minipage on the right?  Thanks.

Comment: @CSR: You can use `\algstore{<name>}` and `\algrestore{<name>}` -- See documentation of the package.